# Design pattern for catching memory leaks in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I have read Apple's memory management guide, and think I understand the practices that should be followed to ensure proper memory management in my application.

At present it looks like there are no memory leaks in my code. But as my code grows more complex, I wonder whether there is any particular pattern I should follow to keep track of allocations and deallocations of objects.

Does it make sense to create some kind of global object that is present throughout the execution of the application which contains a count of the number of active objects of a type? Each object could increment the count of their type in their init method, and decrement it in dealloc. The global object could verify at appropriate times if the count of a particular type is zero of not.

EDIT: I am aware of how to use the leaks too, as well as how to analyze the project using Xcode. The reason for this post is to keep track of cases which may not be detected through leaks or analyze easily.

EDIT: Also, it seems to make sense to have something like this so that leaks can be detected in builds early by running unit tests that check the global object. I guess that as an inexperienced objective-c programmer I would benefit from the views of others on this.

Comment: You can always find the retain count of an object by using `[anObject retainCount]`, so you're system is unnecessary.

Comment: @gurooj As the [ocumentation for `-retainCount`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount) itself states, you shouldn't use that method for debugging memory management (or anything else).

Answer (score 2):

> Each object could increment the count of their type in their init
>   method, and decrement it in dealloc.

To do that right, you'll have to do one of the following: 1) override behavior at some common point, such as NSObject's `-init` or , or 2) add the appropriate code to the designated initializer of every single class. Neither seems simple.

> The global object could verify at appropriate times if the count of a
>   particular type is zero of not.

Sounds good, but can you elaborate a bit on "appropriate times"? How would you know at any given point in the life of your program which classes should have zero instances? You'd have a pretty good idea that there should be no objects at the end of the program, but Instruments could tell you the same thing in that case.

Objective-C has taken several steps to make memory management much simpler. Use properties and synthesized accessors where you can, as they essentially manage your objects for you. A more recent improvement is ARC, which goes even further toward automating most memory management tasks. You basically let the compiler figure out where to put the memory management calls -- it's like garbage collection without the garbage collector. Learn to use those tools well before you try to invent new ones.

Comment: Well my current project is an iPhone game, where each level contains all the objects relevant to it. Hence when one level completes, all of its objects should be dealloced, and this would be the right time to check the counters. I already used synthesized properties and accessors. I can't migrate my project to ARC, as I use some third party libraries which can't be modified at this time.

Comment: Remember that you can disable ARC for individual files if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go that route... it's a pain in single inheritance. Most importantly, there are excellent tools at your disposal which you should master before thinking you must create some global counter. **The global counter exists in a few tools already** -- Learn them!

The way you combat it is to learn how to balance and manage everything correctly when it's written. It's really very simple in hindsight.

ARC is another option -- really that just postpones your understanding.

The first "design pattern" I recommend it to use `release` instead of `autorelease` where possible (although generally more useful for over-releases).

Next, run the leaks instrument/util regularly and fix all leaks/zombies immediately.

Third, learn the existing tools as you go! These tools can do really crazy stuff, like record the backtrace of every allocation and every reference count. You can pause your program's execution and view what allocations exist, alloc counts, backtraces, and all sorts of other stats.

Comment: Can you mention more about the global counter and the other tools you are talking about? (Name etc?) Thanks.

Comment: Instruments.app->Allocations and `heap` are the counters I use most.